# HQL query not working

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

I am doing that query in HQL and is retrieving no results, but when I execute it in
MySQL it works. Could you help me to resolve this problem?

I copied the sql query that is printed in the console when its executed
in my code, and worked in MySQL, exactly the same Query. Thanks for your help

```
    DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(ItineraryDay.class, "itineraryDay");
    subquery.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("itineraryDay.master", "this.master")).setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
    DetachedCriteria tourResults = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Tour.class, "tour");
    tourResults.createAlias("tour.master", "master");
    tourResults.createAlias("master.itinerariesDay", "itinerariesDay");
    tourResults.createAlias("itinerariesDay.itineraryDayDestinations", "itineraryDayDestinations");
    tourResults.createAlias("itineraryDayDestinations.destination", "destination");
    tourResults.createAlias("destination.country", "country");
    tourResults.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.groupProperty("tour.id")));
    if (dateIn != null) {
        tourResults.add(Restrictions.ge("dateIn", dateIn));
    }
    if (dateTo != null) {
        tourResults.add(Restrictions.ge("dateTo", dateIn));
    }
    if (!StringUtils.isBlank(name)) {
        tourResults.add(Restrictions.ilike("master.name", name, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
    }
    if (quantity != null) {
        tourResults.add(Restrictions.le("master.minPassengers", quantity));
        tourResults.add(Restrictions.ge("master.maxPassengers", quantity));
    }

    if (country != null) {
        tourResults.add(Restrictions.eq("country.id", country));
    }

    if (sicDuration != null) {
        tourResults.add(Subqueries.in(sicDuration, subquery));
    }

    // tourResults.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.groupProperty("id")));

    // criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Tour.class));

    Criteria criteria = createCriteria().add(Subqueries.propertyIn("id", tourResults));

    return criteria.list();
```

Comment: What is `createCriteria()` and can you post the MySQL query?

Comment: Does it show any error message in your log?

Comment: It's a method that returns a Criteria element from the actual  class. In this case Tour.class

Comment: No, it shows the SQL Query executed, but it does not return any object.
I execute the same query in MySql and returns the desired results